# Dart convert dynamic to set

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently have data like this:

```
_classes = _items.map((e) => e.ClassID).toSet();
print(_classes);

{One, Two} // output
```

and I am trying to achieve data look like this:

```
{'One', 'Two'}
```

But I can't solve it. Any suggestions why is that?

Comment: Is that output from your IDE console?

Comment: @Blasanka, yes it is.

Comment: Usually IDE console showing without single or double qoute even if they are strings

Answer (score 0):

I already got it after hours of trying and trying different codes.

```
Set<String> _classes;

_classes = _items.map((e) => e.ClassID.toString()).toSet();
```

The `.toString()` part is the one that I am looking for.